# grails withSession and current hibernate session

Tags: hibernate, session, grails

I am confused between withSession in Grails and current hibernate session.

My question is: Is the session object which we have access to in the closure the same as the current hibernate session object?

I wrote a **Service** that has an action as below:

```
def strangeBehavior(){

    Link.withSession { session->
        println "link current session " +  session.hashCode()
    }

    Task.withSession { session->
        println "task current session " +  session.hashCode()
    }

    Project.withSession { session->
        println "project current session " +  session.hashCode()
    }

    UserStory.withSession { session->
        println "user story current session " +  session.hashCode()
    }

    def ctx = AH.application.mainContext
        def sessionFactory = ctx.sessionFactory
        def tmp = sessionFactory.currentSession
        println " current session " +  tmp.hashCode()
    }
}
```

What is strange for me is that there are 5 different hash codes... If I print the 5 session objects, I see the same toString() result. That makes me guess that they have the same contents:

> SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[EntityKey[com.astek.agileFactory.Link#170],
>   EntityKey[com.astek.agileFactory.Project#9]],collectionKeys=[Coll......"

Comment: no, sorry for making you confuse, in the fact, i've just wrote a ordinary service which have a action called strangeBehavioi(), and i run my app with run-app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your question briefly:
The session object which we have access to in closure is **not** the current hibernate session.

The session object is a proxy of the current hibernate session. Hence different hash codes in each case.

Have a look at [source of withSession](https://github.com/SpringSource/grails-data-mapping/blob/master/grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/orm/hibernate/HibernateGormStaticApi.groovy#L435), clearly seen `setExposeNativeSession` is set to `false` (default value is false as well) in [HibernateTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.4/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.html#setExposeNativeSession%28boolean%29) which makes sure to always return a Session Proxy without exposing the native hibernate session.

Comment: thanks dmahapatro !  looking the source code is really a good idea for  clarifying the problems, your explanation is simple but very helpful

Comment: @Greedydp ..If it was helpful, you can make the answer powerful by accepting it. :)